# Codeigniter Session Expired - Update DB

Tags: php, codeigniter

Below is my config session code that will expired in 1min

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 60;
```

Auto logout in 60sec as it will check with the session

```
    //auto logout when time session expired
    if(empty($this->session->userdata("logged_in"))){
        redirect('login/index'); //login page
    }
```

What i wanted is that:

> When logout it will update to DB that show user have been logged out
>   due to inactivity.

Any idea where do i start ?

Answer (score 0):

Before redirecting to login page, you can write a query which will update the status in table:

```
if(empty($this->session->userdata("logged_in"))){
   // something like this
   $query = "UPDATE tbl_name SET isLogout = 'Yes' WHERE user_id = $user_id";
   redirect('login/index'); //login page
}
```

Comment: As for my problem right now is that when session expired it will redirect me back , which i have a problem right now is that i am unable to retrieve my username, therefore when session is expired , it will show error due to my username is "NULL"

Comment: when you login, store user id in session and use in query